# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, puppeteer

I am trying to work with a puppeteer and [datalayer-puppeteer](https://github.com/justusbluemer/puppeteer-datalayer/blob/master/index.js) library to automate GTM containers testing on a website. So far I have written this simple code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const dataLayer = require('puppeteer-datalayer');

(async () => {

    // Automate here
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const containerId = "GTM-5LDMPBF";



    await page.goto('https://www.example.com');
    await page.click('#header > nav > div.main-navigation > a');
    const dataLayerPuppeteer = new dataLayer(page, containerId);
    console.log(await dataLayerPuppeteer.history());


    await browser.close(); 
})();
```

The problem is that when I run it, I get following error: **UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: dataLayer is not defined**. The dataLayer should be defined and visible. Should I somehow wait for the declaration or is there any other way of fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was that you're clicking the link in the main navigation. If you click the link, puppeteer doesn't wait for the subsequent page to load. That means you're trying to read the dataLayer while the page is still loading.
If you remove the link click for testing, it works:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const dataLayer = require('puppeteer-datalayer');

(async () => {

    // Automate here
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const containerId = "GTM-5LDMPBF";

    await page.goto('https://www.ifortuna.sk');
    // await page.click('#header > nav > div.main-navigation > a');

    const dataLayerPuppeteer = new dataLayer(page, containerId);
    console.log(await dataLayerPuppeteer.history);

    await browser.close(); 
})();
```

Another minor issue: dataLayerPuppeteer.history is a getter so it has to be written as `dataLayerPuppeteer.history` instead of `dataLayerPuppeteer.history()`
(the documentation doesn't mention that, I'll add that ;))

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to add some try-catch to your code, maybe it helps you to handle your errors

```
   const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const dataLayer = require('puppeteer-datalayer');

(async () => {
    try {
    // Automate here
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const containerId = "GTM-5LDMPBF";



    await page.goto('https://www.ifortuna.sk');
    await page.click('#header > nav > div.main-navigation > a');
    const dataLayerPuppeteer = new dataLayer(page, containerId);
    console.log(await dataLayerPuppeteer.history());


    await browser.close(); 
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    } finally {
        console.log('We do cleanup here');
    }
})();
```

Comment: still couldn't understand why this is happening

Comment: I tried to implement your code but i got another error ,maybe it's related how are you calling your async code

Comment: you mean from the library? @Ahmed Rebai

Comment: Yes Yes , check the nodejs version that you have or the pckage version installed